# MVVM Binding not working on style applied to DataTemplate in WinRT

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, windows-runtime

I have an application in which I set the width of the element in a property using MVVM.

My Style:

```
<Style x:Key="TileRootSquareGridStyleV2" TargetType="Grid">
         <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding DataContext.SquaredTileWidth , Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding DataContext.SquaredTileWidth, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Style>
```

My DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PhoneFeedTemplateV2">
        <Grid Margin="5"  Style="{StaticResource TileRootSquareGridStyleV2}"  >
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding SquaredTileWidth}"  />  
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I want to be able to reuse my style TileRootSquareGridStyleV2 but I am unable to set the properties Width and Height.  the SquaredTileWidth property with in my object is correctly set because when I launch the application my textblock does show me a number.

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Edit:
I have also tried:

```
<Style x:Key="TileRootSquareGridStyleV2" TargetType="Grid">
         <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding SquaredTileWidth , Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding SquaredTileWidth, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Style>
```

but no luck. However when I set the Height and Width on my Grid it works:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="PhoneFeedTemplateV2">
            <Grid Margin="5"  Width="{Binding SquaredTileWidth}"  Height="{Binding SquaredTileWidth}">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding SquaredTileWidth}"  />  
    </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

EDIT2:
Ok so the answer is: Bindings are not supported on Setters....

Comment: Any errors in the Output Window? Binding errors often show there. If you, *experimentally* add the `Width`/`Height` binding to the Grid directly, does it work?

Comment: @WiredPrairie I have updated my question, but yes it works when I set the binding on the grid, however I would lick to be able to have it in the style if possible?

Comment: See also generalized work-around here: [As the platform evolves, so do the workarounds \[Better SetterValueBindingHelper makes Silverlight Setters better-er!\]](http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9916283)